# Fdroid apps seem to lack permission for SD or sim card (outside of phone storage)?

Tags: permissions, sd-card

I have a rooted Razer Phone 2, and I'm attempting to slowly degoogle. I'm finding some of the apps I've downloaded from fdroid seem to have access (permission?) issues for the SD and/or sim cards, where I have things like my contacts and pictures stored. If I use the google-based apps, there seems to be no issues. I was able to import my contacts .vcf in my contact app (simple mobile tools), but I can only save them to the phone. It states that other programs will be unable to then read the contacts -- attempting to save on the sim pops up with a very quick error message that is replaced by "import failed". I tried to get a video of it via my roommate's new Pixel (as of June), but because the phone sort of "flashes" and lightens the screen, the video attempts to adjust the exposure and it's lost.

I'm not really great at android, but it seems like it's a permissions thing for me. I attempted looking into the /system/etc/permissions/platform.xml file like [this site states](https://www.dtechy.com/unlock-external-sd-card-write-permission-for-all-apps-in-android-lollipop-kitkat/), but I suspected (and was correct) that my Termux wasn't going to be able to save for permission reasons. Additionally, my File Manager (gitlab.com/axet/android-file-manager) doesn't allow me to alter file permissions.

Any suggestions on how to proceed? Am I even on the right track here?

Comment: android apps use (proprietary) APIs (google play services) for access. F-Droid apps might not use it, therefore it's not only a permission issue but apps might not be able to ask for permissions in a proper/intended way. Ask the app developer for troubleshooting

Comment: What apps are you talking about? When were the apps last updated? Which Android version do you use? Do the app explicitly support your Android version? For write access to "external SD-card" (real SD-card, not the emulated internal SD-card) apps need to use the Android Java API, direct file write access is no longer possible since about Android 6. Most apps are not prepared for writing to external SD-cards.

Comment: @alecxs and @ robert I think you've both clarified my problems, which isn't going to be solved easily. As I said, I am unfamiliar with how androids work, but this makes me better understand that it is a permissions thing, and it's not one I can just chmod away. I'll look in to the apps' owner's options. Your input was much appreciated.

Comment: to clarify - when we talking about [android permissions](https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX) this is unrelated to linux file permissions (chown/chmod)

Comment: Yes, I meant I was thinking there was more of a correlation to linux, as I'm way more familiar with that, but still very new there as well. Which is also why both previous comments clarified that misunderstanding.